# Can I use Lightroom 6.14 with tethered capture for a Nikon D850?

Tags: nikon, lightroom-6

I am working for an organization digitizing a photographic archive. Here, we digitize photos using Nikon and Canon cameras, tethered to the computer and using Lightroom 6 to make and directly process the images. It is really important for our workflow to use tethered capture.

Current versions:

- Nikon D800e and D810
- Canon 5Ds R
- Lightroom 6.13 (I have to contact IT to carry out the update)

We would like to upgrade our Nikon cameras to the new Nikon D850. It is said though on the [website of Adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/kb/tethered-camera-support.html) that tethered capture for the Nikon D850 is only supported by Lightroom 7.1. For budgetary reasons, we cannot make the update to the new version of Lightroom with subscription (Lightroom Classic / CC).

So my question: could somebody confirm that it is in fact impossible to use tethered capture with the Nikon D850 using Lightroom 6.14 (= the last perpetual update of Lightroom)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both 6.13 and 6.14, Adobe announced "D850 Support". However, that support was limited to .NEF file support for raw files generated by the D850. As you have found out, tethered shooting with the D850 was not included in those releases.

In a [Nikon D850 Lightroom](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4238859) discussion at dpreview.com, the poster had installed 6.14, and was unable to shoot tethered with their D850.

Comment: You might want to note that, historically, support for tethering newer camera models usually follows a little later than the support for raw files from those same cameras. Of course, past performance is no guarantee of future results.

Comment: In this case, I'm afraid that version 6.14 is the last update of Lightroom 6. This is officially announced by Adobe. Tethering is supported by version 7.1 (Classic, not CC I think), but this is the version with subscription, to which we cannot upgrade for the moment.